# trying to implement GWT cellList

Tags: gwt

I am trying to implement cell List , and insert my data coming from server in my cell List , everything was working fine in celltable but now i have to switch to cellList which is not working

from GWT Show case i made this class

```
         public class EmployerJobCell extends AbstractCell<EmployerJobs> {

@Override
public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
        EmployerJobs value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {

     if (value == null) {
            return;
          }

          sb.appendHtmlConstant("<table>");

          // Add the contact image.
          sb.appendHtmlConstant("<tr><td rowspan='3'>");
          sb.appendHtmlConstant("</td>");

          // Add the name and address.
          sb.appendHtmlConstant("<td style='font-size:95%;'>");
          sb.appendEscaped(value.getJobTitle());
          sb.appendHtmlConstant("</td></tr><tr><td>");
          sb.appendEscaped(value.getJobLevel());
          sb.appendHtmlConstant("</td></tr></table>");



}
```

}

in my view class  i did this

```
            EmployerJobCell jobCell = new EmployerJobCell();
            celllist = new CellList<EmployerJobs>(jobCell);
    celllist.setPageSize(5);
    verticalpanel.add(celllist);
```

but i am not getting any thing on my view .

do i have to  use setRowData as well ?

If yes , how will I get my data

```
           ArrayList<EmployerJobs > values = new ArrayList<EmployerJobs>();
       celllist.setRowData(values);
```

like what will i put in my list

```
          values.  ??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CellList` works fundamentally the same as `CellTable` - both take a list of data, and draw them with a `Cell`. The main difference is that `CellList` only draws one cell with each kind of content, whereas the `CellTable` can draw several, each reading data differently from the model object.

Both implement `HasData`, allowing you to provide data and monitor selection, among other things. So in both cases, you should be calling `widget.setRowData(index, data)` on each to get it to draw the content. So in short, to totally replace the content of a give `CellList` with a `List` called `values`, do something like this:

```
List<EmployerJobs> values = ...
CellList<EmployerJobs> cellList = ...

cellList.setRowCount(0);// clear out existing rows
cellList.setRowData(0, values);// apply new rows
```

Or, more simply, using `AbstractHasData.setRowData(List)`,

```
cellList.setRowData(values); //clear and apply new rows
```

This should get you to the point where you are displaying data.

Using paging makes this a little more complex - generally you use a paging widget like `SimplePager`, and you provide the data not to the `HasData`, but to a data provider, which in turn hands it to the widget, based on the paging information. See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html#paging and http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/javadoc/com/google/gwt/examples/view/AsyncDataProviderExample.java?r=8944 for some examples of how to do this by handing data off to a `DataProvider` for it to manage, and letting an `AbstractPager` allow the user to decide what they want to look at.